# Read IPhone or iPad UUID using web application

Tags: iphone, authentication, ipad, web-applications, uuid

Do you know if is possibile to get the uuid, the result of [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier], using a web app ?
I need to access from iphone/ipad a web page using safari (and not UIwebview under application control) and I should identify the device using its UUID.

For example I would like to send an email Message to a user containing a link. When the receiver opens the link from its device I should autenticate him/her through UUID ?

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

Dario

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No this isn't possible as far as I'm aware.

Comment: You can, if you get user to install a [.mobileconfig profile][1] inside safari.
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781314/getting-a-device-udid-from-mobileconfig]