# Is it possible to get UDID from iPhone safari browser?

Tags: iphone, safari, udid

I need to retrieve UDID (or any other device unique id) from iPhone safari browser (through cookies or request/response header or any other way).
Is it possible if yes how?
thanks

-Z

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read IPhone or iPad UUID using web application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425050/read-iphone-or-ipad-uuid-using-web-application)

Comment: I guess that using iAd it is possible. Do you know how?

Comment: Seems possible. Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072240/read-udid-from-iphone-with-javascript-on-mobile-safari/4964699#4964699) in [Read UDID from Iphone with javascript on mobile safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072240/read-udid-from-iphone-with-javascript-on-mobile-safari) (duplicate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a .mobileconfig
see http://whatsmyudid.com