# Get IMEI from Android using browser like iOS

Tags: android, browser, android-10.0, imei, android-work-profile

In iOS is possible to obtain IMEI using Safari after install a profile in device.E.g:

- https://get.udid.io
- [Is it possible to get UDID from iPhone safari browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726611/is-it-possible-to-get-udid-from-iphone-safari-browser)
- [get iphone ID in web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968323/get-iphone-id-in-web-app)

From Android 10 its't possible obtain IMEI programmatically.I want to know if it is possible to obtain it from Android in a method similar to iOS.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

Also, Google Clearly says "Third-party apps installed from the Google Play Store cannot declare privileged permissions."

For more details regarding the privacy, you can check the below link. 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#data-ids