# get mac address from mobileconfig on iOS device

Tags: ios, mac-address, ota

I'm trying to see if I can get the mac address of iOS devices via the mobileconfig OTA process similar to this post here: [Getting a device UDID from .mobileconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781314/getting-a-device-udid-from-mobileconfig)

I've tried adding 
    MAC_ADDRESS_EN0

within the DeviceAttributes key with pretty much the exact same setup as that other SO post. It's coming back null.

Is there a way to get the mac address or sha1 hash of the mac address via the OTA mobileconfig profile service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That attribute was deprecated in iOS 4, and has been removed in iOS 5.
>   There is no replacement for it.

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3464303?start=0&tstart=0
- http://iphone.vv44.net/thread-18361-1-1.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555386/ios-device-enrollment-challange