# Install Profile Service - Profile Installation Failed (Get UDID from iOS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios

So I followed [this tutorial](http://bendytree.com/tips/Getting-an-iPhone-UDID-from-Mobile-Safari) on how to get the UDID from a iOS device using ASP.NET and C#. I got the .mobileconfig working and it loads up on the iPad. My problem is now though, that when ever I hit "Install" (See picture below) it gives me the error "Profile Installation Failed" - "Invalid Profile".

[image]

I can see the iPad visits my page and gives me the UDID, but I can't seem to find a page that shows me what the iPad wants back.

Right now i'm just returning some xml, but that doesn't work:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<key>status</key>
<string>OK</string>
</plist>
```

[Here is the .mobileconfig im using](http://pastebin.com/bGYWFemY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching high and low I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781314/getting-a-device-udid-from-mobileconfig) by Lakitu which said to do a 301 redirect.

If anyone is interested here is the code I used for redirecting:

```
        context.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Location", "/device/enroll.aspx");
        context.Response.End();
```

I read that you needed to redirect to a directory, but any file seems fine.

Happy coding!

Comment: from where i have to write above? and if i want to store UDID from .mobileconfig file then how can i do this? in asp.net c#

Comment: You have to write a generic handler (.ashx) that sends data to the device.

See http://bendytree.com/tips/Getting-an-iPhone-UDID-from-Mobile-Safari

Here is how I did it:
http://pastebin.com/fZEtiQMd