# Retrieving iPad/iPhone serial number via php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, iphone, ios, ipad

I am trying to retrieve an iPad/iPhone serial number via PHP or Javascript for the purposes of locking an internal website down to a set of serial numbers.

The only thing I have seen that comes close is creating an application installing it via iTunes then that application sends the serial number to the browser which seems quite long winded. Does anyone have any ideas or even another possible unique identifier that can be used on these devices.

Comment: Why not using http-authentication instead of the UUID. Just imagine someone sells/loses his device.

Comment: Currently using http-authentication, was hoping to secure even more, it is for a fairly small amount of units, so easy enough to control uuid. Have also thought about making a browser for this person only with its own unique agent id just to add that little bit more security.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this, even from an iOS application. You will need to choose an alternate method of controlling access to your site.

Answer (score 1):

For your case you actually probably can get the UDID, by getting them to install a .mobileprofile first. (This is something like what testflight or hockeyapp do to register new devices)

See: [Getting a device UDID from .mobileconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781314/getting-a-device-udid-from-mobileconfig)

In general though, your solution seems just wrong to me. Why not just go with some kind of standard password based authentication? Doing this, or implementing user-agent checking will not make it truly any more secure.

Comment: this is for a system to allow users to access parts of the internal systems via the internet, it will only ever be iPads at this stage at least. We are currently using a standard password, username setup but are looking at extra levels of security.It looks like that post might have the answers I need, when i get a working solution I will add it.