# Is there another Hardware specific Code / Number / anything which is able to replace UDID?

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios7, provisioning-profile, udid

assume the following :

I created an ipad app on ios6 which uses the UDID of the ipad before the app can be installed.  So the consumer types in his UDID and than he can install.
In IOS 7 the way I used to get the UDID is not supported anymore, so I search for something else to replace the UDID, if possible.

You may see this question which is somehow related [how to find UDID in ios7 without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032162/is-there-a-way-since-ios-7s-release-to-get-the-udid-without-using-itunes-on-a)

Comment: Have you looked into Advertising Identifier API : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AdSupport/Reference/ASIdentifierManager_Ref/ASIdentifierManager.html?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor be aware that the user can easily rest these and if the user has selected not be be traced these change very often.

Comment: Agreed with that. But if user opts out from Advertising Identifier, it's pointless to chase down the user. That's why Apple is suggesting to use this API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is none, as of iOS 7 you cant even use the MAC address. You should [never identify a device but always a user](http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/uniqueidentifier-deprecated-is-a-good-thing/).

You option could be some kind of registration server, where you app will generate a unique number which it will store in the keychain to persist the value.

Comment: can u tell me something about this process? Is this still possible ? If yes, how does it get the UDID :) ? Device Manager > Iphone / Ipad Right - click Properties > Hardware Tab Properties > Details Tab Property > Device Instance Path

UUID is the last device path listed.

USBVID_05AC&PID_1297UUID String

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean? Just to make clear as of iOS 7 you as a developer can no longer identify a device. All unique identifiers that a device might have can be reset by the user (vendor ID, advertisement ID). You option are to build your own registration server or something that will meet you requirements.