# Ad Hoc won't install on iPad Air (via Web)

Tags: ios, ipad, adhoc

I've build an ad hoc app for a client that should run on different iPads. I put it on my server and set up a web site with a link to install the app. It works on 5 iPads, but not on the 6th, which is an iPad Air. The icon appears and says "installing...", but then it freezes. No more messages.

After reading some threads, here is my checklist so far:

- UDID is included in the ad hoc provisioning profile (I had so many trouble with certificates and profiles in the last years, I think there is nothing I am missing here...)
- the app is build for all architectures (arm7, arm7s, arm64)
- download is done via WiFi
- There is enough disk space on the iPad

I can't check the iPad, because the client is far away. So I'm thinking about buying one to test it myself. But maybe someone has an idea what I am missing.

EDIT UPDATE!!!

I found the answer and it was something I didn't expect. The client simply sent the wrong UDID via one of those "My UDID" apps. Those apps are not working anymore since iOS 7. They send something that looks like an UDID, which will be accepted in the iOS Dev Center, but it is NOT the UDID of the device. Check out this post:

[Q: Is there a way since (iOS 7's release) to get the UDID without using iTunes on a PC/Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032162/is-there-a-way-since-ios-7s-release-to-get-the-udid-without-using-itunes-on-a)

Maybe someone can close this question, because it's misleading...

Comment: Just as an aside, using a 3rd party tool like TestFlight can make this whole process a lot easier.

Comment: If you have recently added the iPad air to the list of ad-hoc devices, a new provisioning profile is generated and you need to beware to build the new file application with the new provisioning profile.

Comment: @robbie_c: Thx, I will have a look at that. But I fear they can't do something with my iOS Dev Account that I cannot do manually

Comment: @thibaultd: I have the newest provisioning profile. I opened it with an editor and the UDID is listed