# Phonegap Build App never installs in iOS 7

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, phonegap-build

I'm developing an App with **Phonegap Build** and **Cordova 3.3.0** for iOS.

I've installed and tested my app in iOS 6 and everything it's ok. I can install it and test it. But when I try to install it in iOS 7 (the same app, the same .ipa), the app stay in "Installing..." and never installs.

Cordova 3.3.0 it supposed to support iOS 7. I verified the **UDID** of my devices are corrects in my iOS Certificates.

Any idea why my Phonegap App in iOS 7 stay in an "**installing loop**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap Build use the **iPhone Developer Certificate (.p12)** and the **Development Provisioning Profile (.mobileprovision)**.

1. Verify the **UDID** of all your devices are correct in your **Provisioning Profile**.
   [How to know my UDID of my Device?](http://whatsmyudid.com/)
2. You have to be sure that **ALL** your test **devices** are added into your Provisioning Profile. If you add new devices later you have to **REGENERATE** your provisioning profile and update your **iOS Sign Key** in your Phonegap Build Panel with the new Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Also worth noting: The UDID application doesn't seem to work on iOS 7.

We used it and it generated a UDID that started with FFFFF.....
We spent ages going around in circles before we realised the UDID should actually look more like a GUID. We grabbed the UDID from iTunes, rebuilt and re-uploaded the provisioning profile - voila!

Comment: @MattQuinn I've never used the "UDID application", which one you refer? I've always get the UDID directly from iTunes. I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032162/is-there-a-way-since-ios-7s-release-to-get-the-udid-without-using-itunes-on-a and you can check http://get.udid.io/ too.