# Programmatically obtaining the IMEI or UDID of an iOS Device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

1.) Does Apple permit developers to retrieve the IMEI number and UDID of user device?

2.) How can I obtain these values programmatically?

3.) If Apple doesn't allow developers to gather the IMEI number, do they provide any other unique number for the device?

Comment: Use CFUUIDCreateString and save it to the key chain. No your not allowed have the the devices UDID. Loads of answers for this on SO please search.

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19032162/is-there-a-way-since-ios-7s-release-to-get-the-udid-without-using-itunes-on-a

Answer (score 1):

Apple no longer allows developers to obtain the UUID programmatically anymore.  There are, however, workarounds that you can use to uniquely identify devices in your app.  The code below allows you to create a unique identifier using `CFUUIDCreate`.

Objective-C:

```
- (NSString*)GUIDString {
    CFUUIDRef newUniqueID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
    CFStringRef newUniqueIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueID);
    NSString *guid = (__bridge NSString *)newUniqueIDString;
    CFRelease(newUniqueIDString);
    CFRelease(newUniqueID);
    return([guid lowercaseString]);
}
```

Swift:

```
func GUIDString() -> NSString {
    let newUniqueID = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault)
    let newUniqueIDString = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault, newUniqueID);
    let guid = newUniqueIDString as! NSString

    return guid.lowercaseString
}
```

Once you have this unique identifier, you can store it in `NSUserDefaults`, Core Data, send it up to a web service, etc, to associate this unique id with the device running your app.  You can also use this as a class method on `NSString` as seen [here](https://github.com/applico/iOS-Categories/blob/master/Objective-C/NSString%2BAdditions.m).

Comment: i am not get to  <key>PayloadUUID</key> <string>C5FB9D0D-0BE7-4F98-82CC-5D0EA74F8CF8</string> <!-- any random UUID --> but I want to need <key>UDID</key> <string>b01ea7bc2237fed21bfe403c6d2b942ddb3c12c3</string>

Comment: Will it produce the same string even after deleting and installing the app?

Comment: @ChanchalRaj No, this answer is purely on an install-by-install basis.